# Javascript .getAttribute() works but .attr() does not

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Try to understand why .getAttribute("id") can get the value but .attr("id") cannot.**

I wrote a Jquery plugin function and try to get the selector or id from the one that uses the plugin function.

In my HTML, the plugin function call is -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    var langObj = {"lang" : "en"};
    var curMap = {"testMap" : "tttt"};

    $("#test_id").testProduct({
        'error_msg'                     : 'ERROR NOT LOAD.'
    }).load(langObj, curMap);
});
</script>
```

In my JQuery plugin function -

```
(function($){

    var pluginName = "testProduct",
        defaults = {};

    $.test.testProduct = function(element, options) {
        this.apiLoadType = {
            'ERROR'         : 'error'
        }

        this.options                = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
        this.element                = element;


        return this;
    };

    $.test.testProduct.prototype = {
        _load: function(langObj, curMap) {
            console.log(this);                             //Chrome console log #1
            console.log(this.element)                      //Chrome console log #2
            this.element.getAttribute("id");  //show the id
            this.element.attr("id");          //not show the id
        },

        //PUBLIC
        load: function(langObj, curMap) {
            var self = this;            
            this._load(langObj, curMap);       
            return this;
        }
    }

    $.fn[pluginName]= function(options) {
        var el = null;
        this.each(function () {
            el = new $.test[pluginName]( this, options );
        });
        return el;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**Chrome console log #1 -**

```
$.testFn.testProduct {apiLoadType: Object, options: Object, element: div#test_id.test_id2, errorElement: null}

  apiLoadType: Object
  element: div#test_id.test_id2
  accessKey: ""
  align: ""
  baseURI: null
  attributes: NamedNodeMap
      0: id
      ...

  className:"test_id2"
  id:"test_id"
  outerHTML: "<div id="test_id" class="test_id2"></div>"
  outerText: ""
  ...
  options: Object
  __proto__: Object
```

Chrome console log #2 -

```
<div id="test_id" class="test_id2"></div>
```

**Why this.element.getAttribute("id"); can show the element id? Which Jquery method should I use to get the selector or element id from my element is this case?**

Comment: `$(this.element).attr("id");` or  just `this.element.id`. `attr()` is a jquery method

Comment: `this.element` is a native DOM element, so it has the method `.getAttribute` - `attr` is a jQuery method, so `$(this.element).attr` should work.

Comment: Strange, I tried this.element.id and it was not work. but now it seems working. Sorry for asking not valuable questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.element` is a native DOM element, accessed via JavaScript, not jQuery, so the `.attr()` jQuery funciton will not work on it.

Try ...

```
$(this.element).attr("id");
```

Answer (score -3):

In javascript you can do this

If you know the id of the element you can do `document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("attribute", "state/value attribute")`

if you wish delete attribute

`document.getElementById("id").removeAttribute("attribute");`